# SQL Cursor (A cursor with the name 'cur_files' does not exist.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bulk_import_csv_from_dir] 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @ext varchar(10),
        @likefilename varchar(max),
        @tablename varchar(max),
        @tabeltemplate varchar(max),
        @directory varchar(8000)


    AS
    BEGIN
        --DECLARE @daily varchar(20);
        DECLARE @filename varchar(255);
        DECLARE @directory_table table (
                    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
                    ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
                    ,depth int
                    ,isfile bit);

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRY
        -----------------------------------------------------------------

        --fill temp table with listed files
        INSERT into @directory_table (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
        EXECUTE master.sys.xp_dirtree @directory,1,1;

        --create cursor file


    execute ('IF OBJECT_ID(''cur_files'') IS NOT NULL DEALLOCATE cur_files');

        SELECT subdirectory as fname FROM @directory_table
        WHERE isfile = 1 AND RIGHT(subdirectory,4) = @ext
        AND subdirectory like @likefilename
        ORDER BY id;


        open cur_files;

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_files 
        INTO @filename

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN


    execute ('IF OBJECT_ID('''+@tablename+''') IS NULL SELECT * INTO '+@tablename+' FROM ' + @tabeltemplate);

        declare @sql varchar(max);



    SET @sql ='BULK INSERT '+@tablename+' FROM '''+@directory+@filename+'''
   WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\n'', ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''', FIRSTROW = 3)';


        execute(@sql);

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_files
            INTO @filename
        END

        close cur_files;
        DEALLOCATE cur_files;

        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT 
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
                ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
                ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
                ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
                ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
                ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            begin
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                execute ('IF OBJECT_ID(''cur_files'') IS NOT NULL DEALLOCATE cur_files');
            end
        END CATCH;

            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
```

this my store procedure
why always show ((A cursor with the name 'cur_files' does not exist.) if execute. what i forget something with this procedure?

thanks

Comment: As you are using a explicit cursor you need to declare the cursor "cur_files" and then the variables used in it then "open cur_files"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning you are Deallocating the **cur_files** `Cursor` you are not declaring the **cur_files** `Cursor` after that,replace

```
execute ('IF OBJECT_ID(''cur_files'') IS NOT NULL DEALLOCATE cur_files');

SELECT subdirectory as fname FROM @directory_table
WHERE isfile = 1 AND RIGHT(subdirectory,4) = @ext
AND subdirectory like @likefilename
ORDER BY id;
```

with

```
DECLARE cur_files CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT subdirectory as fname FROM @directory_table
WHERE isfile = 1 AND RIGHT(subdirectory,4) = @ext
AND subdirectory like @likefilename
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You never declare your cursor. I suspect you want something like

```
--fill temp table with listed files
INSERT into @directory_table (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_dirtree @directory,1,1;

DECLARE cur_files CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  subdirectory AS fname 
    FROM    @directory_table
    WHERE   isfile = 1 
    AND     RIGHT(subdirectory,4) = @ext
    AND     subdirectory LIKE @likefilename
    ORDER BY id;

OPEN cur_files;
```

I have removed the check to deallocate the cursor if it exists, since I have added the `LOCAL` option in the declaration it will only exist in the current scope, and since you have not already declared it, it cannot already exist, so this is a redundant check. The other options are just to improve memory management, and keep your cursor as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have two major issues here. First is you don't declare your cursor. The second is that you are using dynamic sql to check for the existence of your cursor. This line is never going to do anything because dynamic sql runs in its own scope. This is easy enough to prove.

```
declare cur_files cursor for select * from sys.objects

execute ('IF OBJECT_ID(''cur_files'') IS NOT NULL DEALLOCATE cur_files');

DEALLOCATE cur_files
```

Comment: Notice that the deallocate outside of dynamic sql will not throw an exception. Also, cursors are not created as a system object so the check you are making is not valid in the first place.